# get the attribute from a string

Tags: string, button, tkinter, attributes

I'm trying to desable an entry when a button is pushed. They are 15 different buttons for 15 entrys so I've created a loop. But I cannot acces the attribute config of a string that I need to use to select the right entry. I don't know if it's really clear. Here is some of my code that doesn't work. I don't know how to do it.

```
def Aleatoire_presse(numCase):
("entry"+str(numCase)).config(state='disabled')

for z in range (1,16):
    entryz = tk.Entry(frame, bg= "#C4CFE1")
    entryz.place(relx= (0.2), rely=(0.05*z), relwidth= 0.2, relheight = 0.03)

for z in range (1,16):    
    buttonz = tk.Button(frame, text="Aleatoire", bg = "#7392C4", command=lambda: Aleatoire_presse(z))
    buttonz.place(relx= (0.5), rely=(0.05*z), relwidth= 0.2, relheight = 0.03)
```

And here is the error message :

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'config'
```

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: It looks like you are trying to access a button by its name. However, when you construct the name `("entry"+str(numCase))`, all you have is just a string of the name (e.g., the string `"entry1"`). It seems like you will need to use a function to get the actual "button" variable, which you can then call `.config` on.

Answer (score 1):

You must store the entry widgets in a list or dictionary.

```
def Aleatoire_presse(numCase):
    entries[numCase].config(state='disabled')

entries={}
for z in range (1,16):
    entryz = tk.Entry(frame, bg= "#C4CFE1")
    entryz.place(relx= (0.2), rely=(0.05*z), relwidth= 0.2, relheight = 0.03)
    entries[z] = entryz
```